# Java android connect to device by Bluetooth

Tags: android, bluetooth

I try to connect to the device used by  Bluetooth. When I try to connect I get :

```
java.io.IOException: read failed, socket might be closed or timeout, read ret: -1
```

**I do this:**

```
BluetoothSocket mmSocket;

 public ConnectThread(BluetoothDevice device) {
            mmDevice = device;
            BluetoothSocket tmp = null;
            // Get a BluetoothSocket for a connection with the
            // given BluetoothDevice
            try {
                tmp = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
            mmSocket = tmp;
        }
```

**And when I do this :**

```
mmSocket.connect();
```

I get a exceptions

This is my connect thread :

```
private class ConnectThread extends Thread {
    private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
    private final BluetoothDevice mmDevice;

    public ConnectThread(BluetoothDevice device) {
        mmDevice = device;
        BluetoothSocket tmp = null;
        // Get a BluetoothSocket for a connection with the
        // given BluetoothDevice
        try {
            tmp = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
        mmSocket = tmp;
    }

    public void run() {
        setName("ConnectThread");
        // Always cancel discovery because it will slow down a connection
        mAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
        // Make a connection to the BluetoothSocket
        try {
            // This is a blocking call and will only return on a
            // successful connection or an exception
            mmSocket.connect();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            connectionFailed();
            // Close the socket
            try {
                mmSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e2) {
                e2.printStackTrace();
            }
            // Start the service over to restart listening mode
            BluetoothChatService.this.start();
            return;
        }
        // Reset the ConnectThread because we're done
        synchronized (BluetoothChatService.this) {
            mConnectThread = null;
        }
        // Start the connected thread
        connected(mmSocket, mmDevice);
    }

    public void cancel() {
        try {
            mmSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where exactly are you connecting? Can you show a [mcve]?

Comment: And are you able to [discover devices](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth#DiscoverDevices)?

Comment: @cricket_007 yes I dicover my device also I have a whole data about device

Comment: @cricket_007 it works when I connect to another phone but when I try Connect to device which have a bluetooth I get this exception

Comment: That my UUID thing isn't meant to be used by other devices. It's specific to the divice you're connecting to, I believe